# Maven compile is throwing an error with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I need to have all of the required jar files included in the executable jar that I'm trying to produce. In Eclipse I can export the jar with all included jar files and everything works.

So, after everything is working through Eclipse, I am now looking to add Maven to the mix. I have produced the pom that is at the bottom of the question. Our company has Artifactory and all of the dependencies are copying correctly. If I build as maven-jar-plugin, the builds works just fine, except that the libs directory has to be reachable to the final executable jar.

So, I'm trying to use maven-assembly-plugin to have everything packaged together in one file. But, if I use Maven the build dies with the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) on project ExpectedResults: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file-set for 'maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3' to archive: Error adding archived file-set. PlexusIoResourceCollection not found for: C:\Users\crouchkl\.m2\repository\maven-plugins\maven-cobertura-plugin\1.3\maven-cobertura-plugin-1.3.plugin: No such archiver: 'plugin'. -> [Help 1]`

Here is the pom

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.klccomputing.sses.expectedResults</groupId>
  <artifactId>ExpectedResults</artifactId>
  <version>R4.21</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/libs
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.klccomputing.sses.expectedResults.ExpectedResults</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <finalName>ExpectedResults</finalName>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>      
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <blaze.version>7.6.1</blaze.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>AdvCommon</artifactId>
        <version>${blaze.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>Advisor</artifactId>
        <version>${blaze.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>AdvisorDev</artifactId>
        <version>${blaze.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>AdvisorSvr</artifactId>
        <version>${blaze.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>FileDialog</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>InnovatorRT</artifactId>
        <version>${blaze.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>license</artifactId>
        <version>${blaze.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.klccomputing.sses.sse</groupId>
        <artifactId>SSEProductDecisionSchema</artifactId>
        <version>R4.21.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.klccomputing.sses.rulesutil</groupId>
        <artifactId>SSERulesUtil</artifactId>
        <version>R4.21.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <url>ExpectedResults</url>
</project>
```

Comment: First why do you need dependency-maven-plugin? Furthermore why have you changed `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`? Why haven't you defined the version for maven-assembly-plugin? What about all other plugins etc not pinned as well? What I don't understand: ` If I build as maven-jar-plugin, the builds works just fine, except that the libs directory has to be reachable to the final executable jar.` ?

Comment: Number 1: I don't know what I'm doing. I've pulled code from all over the internet to try and get this to work. I thought that I needed the dependency-maven-plugin so that the jar would be in one place. Number 2: What do you mean by 'change' the source directory? Shouldn't it be defined? Number 3: I just looked in Artifactory and have now added the latest version 3.3.0. The build still dies with the same error. Number 4: The executable jar file will error because it cannot find the other jar files in the class path.